# Express Gateway detect authenticated user by cookie

Tags: express, express-gateway

I'm new to express gateway, I've created login in my user service and created oauth2 credentials in gateway, got the secret key and store it as httpOnly cookie on client. Now I have a protected route that I want authenticated users be able to work with, here is my code in gateway config file :

```
pipelines:
...
users:
    apiEndpoints:
      - users
    policies:
      - oauth2:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: users
```

But it doesn't recognize secret from client cookie. How can I make it work?

Comment: Can you log the headers in gateway-config.yml and confirm the header holding the secret is present?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod I'm using Postman, and it shows the cookie